# How to handle cross referencing visibility for two separate divs with angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have started to work on an angular js project. Now I am stuck in the following situation.  Please give me some pointers to start on.

I have two divs a) contains a list of images as anchors; this list is created by ngRepeat directive. b) when an image is clicked in the first div, this div will be visible and will be filled with the data defined at the images. This has to  somehow cross reference the data in container two. What is the best angular way to achieve such effects?  I am not using jquery with angular.

Comment: Share some code..the object that you use for `ng-repeat`ing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide some more code but, the general idea is. At you scope level define a property

`$scope.selectedImage`

In the ng-repeat div's do something like this

`<div ng-repeat="image in images" ng-click='selectedImage=image'>`

Now the other div can do binding on `selectedImage` property.

Hope it make sense. Share some more details so that we can help.